# Can I get copies of Ubuntu 13.04 on CD's to give our Free Software Club members?

Tags: cd

I want the new Ubuntu 13.04 to give to our club members for free. Can get them?

I have a club named **'Free Software Club'**  with 100+ members. We discuss free software, Linux, Python and give training.

Comment: This is a valid question. He's asking the process to getting Ubuntu CDs for distribution. Everyone saying "Just burn your own" is essentially tantamount to "RTFM" and "Google it".

Answer (score -1):

If you mean Ubuntu Desktop go to [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn it to CD.

For Ubuntu Server got to [Download Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)